# Select option passing null to database

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I have a view as below:

```
<select ng-model="d" ng-options="k.id as k.name for k in act"></select>
<input type="submit" value="Create" ng-click="CreateOpen(Emp)" class="btn btn-default" />
</div>
```

My Js is as below:

```
app.factory('crudServiceUser', function ($http) {
    crudUserObj = {};
  crudUserObj.Create = function (openact) {
        var Emp;
        Emp = $http({
            method: 'Post',
            url: '/Employee/BankAccount/Index',
            data: openact
        }
        ).then(function (response) {
            return response.data;
        });
        return Emp;
    }
return crudUserObj;
});

app.controller('usersController', function ($scope, crudServiceUser) {
 $scope.CreateOpen = function (openact) {
        crudServiceUser.Create(openact).then(function (result) {

            $scope.Msg = alert(result.EName + " Has Been Created Successfully");

        })
    }
```

Here is my action method:

```
public ActionResult Index(tblOpenAct tblopact)
        {            
          if (ModelState.IsValid)
          {                
           objemp.OpenActBs.Insert(tblopact);  
           return RedirectToAction("Index");

          }                
        return View(tblopact);        

       }
```

But the select option is inserting null to database but if I use textbox then it inserts data.

Comment: Close your select: `<select ng-model="d" ng-options="k.id as k.name for k in act"></select>`

Comment: I have closed it in my code.But still its displaying null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like bellow

```
<select ng-model="d" >
<option ng-repeat="k in act" value="{{k.id}}">{{k.name }}     </option>
</select>
```

Comment: what is the relvent property for Emp object. let's say dept_Id     <select ng-model="Emp.dept_id" >